# Mysql query to replace name based on id of another table

Tags: mysql, sql

i have two tables clients and well_names

**Table Clients**

```
id,name
1   ABC
2   TEST
3   XYZ
```

**Table well_names**

```
id,operator
1   ABC
2   ABC
3   ABC
4   TEST
5   TEST
6   XYZ
7   XYZ
```

I want to select id from clients tables and update on operator column in well_names table.

**Expected output**

Table well_names

```
id,operator
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   2
5   2
6   3
7   3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE well_names WN
INNER JOIN Clients C ON WN.operator = C.operator 
set WN.operator = C.id
```

Answer (score 1):

This query will work:

```
SELECT a.id, b.id 
FROM clients as a LEFT JOIN well_names as b ON a.name = b.operator
```

Comment: Believe you have a typo in the SQL b.operator, you're missing the o

Comment: In SQL this will fail since you cant have twice the same colomn name  I would suggest:   SELECT a.id, b.id as operator
FROM clients as a LEFT JOIN well_names as b ON a.name = b.operator

Comment: there is no pb, i think; and it will be performed. because the request is to show id from clients while operator id (that is selecting from well-names table) is capturing to show the row number, and when operator and the name is matching, value of the id from clients table will shown in front of well-names id row.
of curse i understand your mean, and it's true 
must be b.id as operator

Answer (score 0):

```
select w.id as id, 
       c.id as operator
from join tbl_well w 
inner tbl_client c
on c.operator = w.operator
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subquery` with update statement :

```
update well_names w
      set operator = (select c.id from Clients c where c.name = w.operator);
```